# What is the possible scenarios for child entity to be half persisted in JPA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, eclipselink

Im using EclipseLink and Spring @Tranasctional annotations.

Classes are like following:

```
@Entity 
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
public abstract class Base{
    Long x;
    Long y;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("child")
public class Child extends Base{   
    Long z;
    Long w;   
}
```

And method is like following:

```
@Transactional
public void doSomething(){
    if(somethingWrong){
        throw new MyCheckedException();
    }

    entityManager.persist(new Child(1, 2, 3, 4));
}
```

Once I found in DB following:

```
 id | type  | x | y |  z   |  w   |
-----------------------------------
 7  | child | 1 | 2 | NULL | NULL |
```

I can`t reproduce this behaviour. How it is possible?

Some additional info about `z` and `w`:
`z` is id-value of some just pulled from DB entity. `w` is other value which nohow may be null. Moreover, if one of `w` or `z` would be `null` before call of `persist`, `NullPointerException` would have been thrown.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure this row in DB was produced with the same code ? It could be a row inserted manually or even a row from previous versions of the code...

Comment: Hello Gaël! So cases  are impossible - code is fresh and nobody could insert this row manually

Comment: Turn on logging to finest, and you might want to change one of the two columns temporarily to have a not-null constraint so an exception is thrown on the problem insert to show exactly where in the code this is being caused from.  Please note that the code you provided is incomplete - Child isn't extending the Base class as you intended.  It's a cut and paste error i'm sure, but something easily overlooked in the actual code might be causing or related to this issue.

Comment: Hi @Chris, thanks  for reply! It is a good idea too turn on logging and set not-null constraint,  this steps will help me to recognize, what exactly happened. But now I cant even reproduce this behavior and need help in locating possible source of such kind of behavior. Full code is confusing, sorry for typo. But `z` is `id`-value of just pulled from DB entity. `w` is other value which nohow may be null. Moreover, if one of `w` or `z` would `null` before call of `persist`, `NullPointerException` would have been thrown .